# Conditional Statements within OpenCart

Tags: php, conditional-statements, opencart

I'm trying to do something that I think is pretty basic within OpenCart. I want to have a section ONLY display on one information page which is within a tpl file. I have tried this code:

```
<?php if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'mith_source')) { ?>
```

with the closing else etc at the end.

I'm hoping that there is a simple solution to this issue. As I would also like to be able to use this within the header.tpl to call some specific CSS and JS files for just this page only.

Comment: Just to clarify, the actual url is: http://www.sitename.com/mith_source

Comment: Also have tried `<?php if(!empty($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'mith_source') : ?>` which also doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved with an update to Opencart